# Mapping all variables with mediator in one

Tags: wso2, transform

I'm mapping variables in XSLT file but I have lots of variables to map. Is there any mediator to do this in `WSO2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

should work. Please try it.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 has its own XSLT mediator why don't you try that one.

Syntax

```
    <xslt key="string" [source="xpath"]>
         <property name="string" (value="literal" | expression="xpath")/>*
         <feature name="string" value="true| false" />*
         <resource location="string" key="string"/>*
    </xslt>
```

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/XSLT+Mediator

Comment: I tried this one but there is any mentioned with mapping all variables at once.